# Gitlab runner starting another job before one before it finishes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have one gitlab runner configured for a single project. The issue that I am seeing is that the runner will not wait until the prior job finished, and instead does a checkout in the same directory as the prior job and stomps over everything. I have one job already running, and then another develop commits and thus another job is started. Why can't I configure the pipeline not to run so that it doesn't corrupt the already running workspace?

Here is the log from both of the jobs (only difference is the timestamp)

```
[0K] Running with gitlab-runner 12.6.0 (ac8e767a)
[0K]  on gitlab.xxxx.com rz8RmGp4
[0K] section_start:1578357551:prepare_executor
[0K] Using Docker executor with image my-image-build ...
[0K] Using locally found image version due to if-not-present pull policy
[0K] Using docker image sha256:xxxxxxxxxx for my-image-build ...
[0;msection_end:1578357553:prepare_executor
[0Ksection_start:1578357553:prepare_script
[0K] Running on runner-rz8RmGp4-project-23-concurrent-0 via gitlab.xxxx.com...
section_end:1578357554:prepare_script
[0K] section_start:1578357554:get_sources
[0K[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 50...[0;m
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/my-project/.git/
<proceeds to checkout and stomp over the already running runner>
```

Main issue I see is that they both checkout to the same directory of `Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/my-project/.git/` which causes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [resource_group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#resource_group) to keep jobs from running in parallel.

e.g.

```
Job 1:
  stage: My Stage
  resource_group: stage-wedge
  ...
Job 2:
  stage: My Stage
  resource_group: stage-wedge
  ...
```

In the above example Job 2 will run after Job 1 is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Jobs of same stage are executed in parallel.
if you need it to be sequential, you may add a stage for each of those jobs.

see the docs 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages

In case of multiple pipelines running you may want to configure your gitlab-runner options: limit / concurrent

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html

Comment: I understand this. My issue is that I have two separate commits that trigger a pipeline build on two different branches. For some reason, the second trigger continues to run and checkout the source code in the same directory as the one before it. I want to limit subsequent pipeline triggers from running until the first is finished or else the working directory is being used by two processes.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I missunderstood, I did updated my answer including the suggestion by setting limit / concurrent setting in gitlab-runner.